# I can't install anything with pip

Tags: python, pip

i tried installing numPy using this command

$  pip install numpy

and this is what i get

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe" install numpy': The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: [pip] Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process

Answer (score 1):

Because the path of pip is not "C:\Python310\Scripts\pip.exe"
You can install numpy with `python -m pip install numpy`, or download pip in https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run `python get-pip.py` to install pip, after that you can install package with `pip install numpy`